# About function db.execSQL() in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am a beginner. I learn to `SQLite`. I don't understand function **db.execSQL**`(DATABASE_CREATE)`;

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table users (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "  + "name text not null);";
```

So function `db.execSQL()`. How do it word? Please help me. Thank,

Comment: your question is unclear

Answer (score 8):

From the [Android SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) for `SQLiteDatabase`:

`execSQL(String sql): Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.`

In your example, to create the table, you would call `db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE)` which would execute your table create statement on your application's SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

this is the actual database where your data is stored. When you
created your database with SQLiteOpenHelper class, it sets everything in motion to
create your database but holds off until you are ready to use that database. And the
way SQLiteOpenHelper knows that you are ready to use your database is when you
access that database either with getReadableDatabase() or getWritableDatabase()
for read and write operations respectively.

Comment: This didn't answer the question at all